# For the function $f(x) = (x-1)(x-3)(x-5)$ in interval [0,4], find the value of $C$ of Lagrange's mean value theorem.

Tags: calculus

> For the function $f(x) = (x-1)(x-3)(x-5)$ in interval [0,4], find the value of $C$ of Lagrange's mean value theorem.

I used Lagrange's Mean value theorem, and differentiated the function to get $(x-1)(x-3)+(x-5)(x-1)+(x-5)(x-3) = 3$ and after it I opened all the brackets to get the final result $C = \frac{9 - \sqrt {21}}{3}$.

> But this is a very long method to do for 1 marks question, Please tell me any other shorter approach to this problem.

Comment: I can't see a simpler method, at least without being too particular about this function (but that would also take time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess they want you to say $$f'(x)=(x-1)(x-3)+(x-5)(x-1)+(x-5)(x-3)$$ and note this is a quadratic, and so determined by its values at three points.  We have
$$\begin{align}
f'(1)&=8\\f'(3)&=-4\\f'(5)&=8\end{align}$$ so by  inspection, $$f'(x)=3(x-3)^2-4$$ and then you solve for $f'(x)=3.$

Still seems like a lot of work for one point to me.